# The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I searched a lot about this, but none of them could help me.

When I run my project, I get this error:

> /home/ali/Desktop/personalitytest-backend/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:428
>           throw new MongooseError('The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a ' +
>           ^
>       MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to
>   `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.

My index.js file:

```
const express = require('express'),
  app = express(),
  mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  rateLimit = new require('express-rate-limit')({
    windowMs: 1000 * 60 * 10,
    max: 500,
    handler: (req, res) => {
      res.json({
        data: 'Your request was too much, please try again in 10 minutes later.',
        status: 'error'
      })
    }
  });
const Application = new class {
  constructor() {
    this.setConfig();
    this.setupDB();
    this.setRouters();
    this.setupExpress();
  }
  setConfig() {
    require('dotenv').config();
    app.use(require('helmet')());
    app.use(express.json());
  }
  setupDB() {
    mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
    mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true });
  }
  setRouters() {
    app.use('/', require('./routes'));
  }
  setupExpress() {
    app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${process.env.PORT}.`));
    // app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${process.env.PORT}.`));
  }
}
```

My .env file:

```
PORT=3000
DATABASE_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/PersonalityTest
JWT_SECRETKEY=asfdawetq312etr%!@$qe
```

If I simply write database url in mongoose.connect method, there will be no error.

For example, this doesn't have error:

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/PersonalityTest", { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true });
```

Answer (score 27):

To read the `.env`-file you'll need to install something that will read that file, for instance the `dotenv` package

```
npm install dotenv --save
```

Then you [require that package in your code](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv#usage)

```
require('dotenv').config();
```

And according to the `dotenv` documentation you should do it

> As early as possible in your application, require and configure dotenv.

Next you might need to add double quotation marks around your `DATABASE_URL` value

```
DATABASE_URL="mongodb://localhost:27017/PersonalityTest"
```

Comment: I did all of the items but did not get the result and still has error.

Comment: I think the problem is about requiring env package.

Comment: According to the `dotenv` documentation you should add `require('dotenv').config();` "[a}s early as possible in your application, require and configure dotenv". I've never seen anybody use require the way you do here. Try placing it at the top of your `index.js` file

Answer (score 12):

Have you checked if your .env variables can be readed from that index.js file?

For example,check out what you get when you log some of them to the console:

```
console.log(process.env.DATABASE_URL);
```

If you get 'undefined', then you could try especifiying the absolute path for your .env file like this:

```
const path = require('path');
require('dotenv').config({ path: path.resolve(__dirname, './.env') });
```

I struggled with this problem recently and in my case that solved the issue. Regards.

Answer (score 5):

This work for me

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
dotenv.config({path:__dirname+'/.env'});
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to declare `.env` file after installing dotenv package.

Answer (score 2):

move the .env file from the routes folder or any other folder. And don't place it in any particular folder just let it be in the main folder just like app.js or index.js whichever you have. This might work!

Comment: Yes. Be sure your .env file is in the root of your project (turned out to be my problem)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the .env file is named `.env` and not `config.env` or anything else.
I had this problem from following a tutorial online and only recently figured out why I got this error.

[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vufzj.png)

[console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBiTQ.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. FYI, All error messages, code, data, et al must be embedded as text, not images of text, which is not copy-pastable into search engines, or code editors. Images of text can also be difficult to read, especially on mobile devices, & can consume undue data on mobile as well. Please `edit` to bring up to guidelines. Finally, this reads more like a Comment than an Answer, so it may be deleted as "not an Answer" by the platform. Once you have enough rep, you can leave Comments anywhere. You can read more about SO guidelines at StackOverflow.com/help. Looking forward to more insights

Comment: This solves my problem actually. Not sure why my .env file has been deleted. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

to put :
`require('dotenv').config();`
at the top of the file where all the other "require" are.
Then add `process.env.DATABASE_URL`  in a variable:
`const source = process.env.DATABASE_URL;`

and therefore at the top of the file you will have:

```
require ('dotenv'). config ();
const source = process.env.DATABASE_URL;
```

lower:

```
mongoose.connect (source, {useNewUrlParser: true});
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your .env file is also located at the same path where you are executing the nodemon command. Or else you will have to declare the path of .env as in the answer of @oxk4r

Answer (score 1):

I had this error and funny enough I had another project that uses a similar setup. Went to that project and started it up with the same .env values and it had no issues.

So I copied the code over the my current project and started the current one but did not want to connect to the mongodb if I have it setup like this `mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },`

and will only work if I use it like this `mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:3000/posts", { useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true });`

The thing that bothered me is that it works in one project but not in the other so I decided I'm going to delete my `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` file and reinstall everything.

After that everything worked.

Also Check if you dont have another `node_modules` folder that is clashing with your current one. if so delete both with your `package-lock.json` file and reinstall again. make sure you are in the correct directory as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config({ path: './config.env' });

const DB = process.env.DATABASE.replace(
  '<PASSWORD>',
  process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD
);

mongoose
  .connect(DB, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then((con) => {
    // console.log(con.connections);
    console.log('DB connection successful');
  });
 const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
 app.listen(port, () => {
       console.log(`app running on port ${port}...`);
  });
```

1. Now the problem you facing is related to the path of // `config.env` to check that you accessing is correct// `console.log(process.env);` so that it will show you are get access of `.env`, if not then your path-

   ```
    require('dotenv').config({ path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../.env') });
   ```

Now again `console.log(process.env)` if you get this in your console read their property is mentioned in `config.env` file present.

2. Check the link of your `DATABASE` and `DATABASE_PASSWORD` is correct or not or go to mongoDB Atlas change your password for your cluster and again try it

Answer (score 1):

Your `DATABASE_URL` is `undefined` because your `.env` file cannot be accessed in the root folder.

Therefore, after importing the dotenv and setting it to `config()`, make sure your `.env` file is not saved in another folder. It should always be in the root folder where it can be accessed.

Then in your `index.js` file:

[image: a code snippet]

Answer (score 0):

I know what the problem is. 
 Make sure first you write dotenv.config({path: './config.env'}); And then you use your process.env.DATABASE_URL

Don't use process.env.DATABASE_URL before dotenv.config({path:'./config.env'});

Answer (score 0):

Reference to the github repository:
https://github.com/realabbas/serverless-lambda-node-express-mongodb

Extending oxk4r's answer, I have the following tree showing the directory structure of the app:

```
.
├── code-of-conduct.md
├── .env
├── .gitignore
├── _config.yml
├── contributing.md
├── lib
│   ├── app.js
│   ├── db.js
│   └── routes
│       ├── index.js
│       └── notes
│           ├── note.js
│           └── notes.controller.js
├── LICENSE
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── README.md
├── secrets.json
├── server.js
└── serverless.yml
```

We primarily use the dotenv package to reference the environmental variables in the .env file.
The important thing to note here is db.js and the .env files. We need to reference the .env file from the db.js file. We do as below:

db.js

```
const path = require('path');
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
require('dotenv').config({ path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../.env') });
console.log('here...', path.resolve(__dirname, '../.env'), process.env.MONGODB_URL)

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL
   , { useNewUrlParser: true })
```

.env

```
MONGODB_URL="mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/game-of-thrones"
```

As we see the tree, the .env file id one level above the db.js file. So, we reference it by the path package as:

```
 path.resolve(__dirname, '../.env')
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it still persisted even after following all that was stated here. Was losing my mind until I went over the .env and realised I typed `DB_NAME:mongodb+srv:/.....`, changed it to `DB_NAME=mongodb+srv:/.....` and the variable was no longer undefined, Mongoose was able to read it.

Answer (score 0):

Check your key and value in your Heroku Config Vars under your app settings.  Seems silly, but I had MONGODB_URL instead of _URI and it took me forever to realize my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI).then(() => {
    console.log('DB Conected...')
})

In my case while connecting to database, I wrote wrong spelling of MONGO_URI , I wrote MANGO_URI there (but in .env file I had given name as MONGO_URI), Please do check & correct it, I know it not proper solution but sometime we do such small mistakes.
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that when I write

```
dotenv.config();
```

before

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.LOCAL_MONGO);
```

and my problem solved.

Not written in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config();
```

Or:

```
const dotenv = require("dotenv");

dotenv.config();
```

No need to add `""` for database URL.

Answer (score 0):

Change the .env file to the root of your app at the same level as the package.json

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a `.env` file and provide `MONGOURI` in it.

Example:

```
MONGO_URI=mongodb+srv://<password>@cluster0.wlhevoe.mongodb.net/test
```

2.In `index.js` , require like this

```js
const dotenv = require('dotenv')

dotenv.config({ path: './.env' }) // Here you must take care to provide the correct path of the .env file
```

3. 

```js
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true })
  .then(() => console.log('DB Connection Successful'));
```

This worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please just try to have this order/configuration one after onther.

```
dotenv.config();
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL)
  .then(() => {
    console.log('connected to db');
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err.message);
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I had left out the brackets after the word config. So the correct config is below. No more errors now.

require('dotenv').config()

Comment: In this case, we can see the user did not forget the parenthesis. But if the issue *were* a missing set of `()`, that would be considered a typo. In case of typos, Please do help the OP, but the correction should be left as a *Comment* to the post, NOT as an *Answer*. Know also, that the Q will be "closed" as off topic, a typo, or not helpful to future users. You can even flag the post as a typo yourself, if you like. *(BTW, brackets are [ ], parenthesis are ( ), and braces are { } ).*

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for the console.log() suggestion.
I console.log my MongoURI connection string, and it returned it.
And it immediately connected after i did this.
No idea why it didn't before this, as that was the only change.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34615299)

Answer (score -1):

This happened to me recently, my mouse was having an issue, so I mistakenly moved my `.env` file out of my server.js folder.

Firstly, check if the `.env` file if its in the server folder.

Secondly, make sure you install something to read the `.env` file i.e

```bash
npm install dotenv --save
```

Thirdly, [require that package in your code](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv#usage) i.e

```js
import dotenv from 'dotenv'
dotenv.config()
```

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPAHG.png)