# throw new Mongoose Error ('The ''uri'' parameter should be "openuri")

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

**If anyone can understand my issue,I went through many posts but I didn't found anything which is helpful**

This is my index.js file

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const dotenv = require("dotenv");
require("dotenv").config();

//Import Routes
const authRoute = require("./routes/auth");

//connnect to DB
mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_CONNECT, { useNewUrlParser: true }, () =>
  console.log("Connected To DB!")
);

//Middlewares
app.use(express.json());

//route Middleware
app.use("/api/user", authRoute);
app.listen(3000, () => console.log("server up and Running"));
```

This is .env file

```js
DB_CONNECT = 'mongodb+srv://username:<password>@cluster0.5tnd3.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
PORT = 3000
```

> 

This is the error I am getting in my terminal

```js
    throw new MongooseError('The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a ' +
    ^

MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (C:\COURSES\Authentication-nodeJS\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:694:11)
    at C:\COURSES\Authentication-nodeJS\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:350:10
    at promiseOrCallback (C:\COURSES\Authentication-nodeJS\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:9:12)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (C:\COURSES\Authentication-nodeJS\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1154:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (C:\COURSES\Authentication-nodeJS\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:349:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\COURSES\Authentication-nodeJS\index.js:12:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

```js
(node:4364) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (C:\COURSES\Authentication-nodeJS\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:694:11)
    at C:\COURSES\Authentication-nodeJS\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:350:10
    at C:\COURSES\Authentication-nodeJS\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:31:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (C:\COURSES\Authentication-nodeJS\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:30:10)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (C:\COURSES\Authentication-nodeJS\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1154:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (C:\COURSES\Authentication-nodeJS\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:349:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\COURSES\Authentication-nodeJS\index.js:13:4)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:4364) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:4364) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

And Now I am getting this weird error.but its showing that DB is connected.Can anyone please help me

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you seen this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55267494/the-uri-parameter-to-openuri-must-be-a-string-got-undefined/55267839

Comment: I have followed all these steps buddy But Couldn't find exact solution.

Comment: make sure that you are reading the config the right way, just place a console.log() before the connect function and check the value of `process.env.DB_CONNECT` and also you don't need this line `const dotenv = require("dotenv");`

Comment: Did you read the error?

Answer (score 1):

```js
server up and Running Successfully and DB Connected
(node:11416) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: Authentication failed.
    at MessageStream.messageHandler (C:\COURSES\Authentication-nodeJS\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:268:20)
    at MessageStream.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at processIncomingData (C:\COURSES\Authentication-nodeJS\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:144:12)
    at MessageStream._write (C:\COURSES\Authentication-nodeJS\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:42:5)
    at writeOrBuffer (internal/streams/writable.js:358:12)
    at MessageStream.Writable.write (internal/streams/writable.js:303:10)
    at TLSSocket.ondata (internal/streams/readable.js:719:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:309:12)
    at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:284:9)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:223:10)
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:11416) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:11416) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

*emphasized text*you can follow the following steps, I think your code should work after this

1. replace this below inside your variable with the actual username and password of your account on the MongoDB site

```
://username:<password>
```

```
DB_CONNECT = 'mongodb+srv://username:<password>@cluster0.5tnd3.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority'

to something like this

MONGO_URL_TEST= "mongodb+srv://myname:myapssword@cluster0.z4ta5.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
```

2. work around these deprecation warnings with Mongoose provided options

```
const options = {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useCreateIndex: true,
  useFindAndModify: false,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
};
mongoose.connect(MONGO_URL, options);
```

3. no need for this

```
const dotenv = require("dotenv");

below is enough

require('dotenv').config();
```

4.make sure your .env file is at the root of your file not inside any folder

read more here:

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html

*Server is Running But Still Getting These Errors and Warnings. Should I really worry about this? Because I am getting empty data in postman if I verify*

Comment: @Siddarth A what sort of error messages u are getting?

Comment: Hey Bro Server is running and DBis connected too.But I am getting the above error and warning at the same time.I even changed the mongoose verion from new to older version.But still I couldn't recognise.I am stuck

Comment: Thanks It's Working now with the older version of the mongoose package.