# I am running Express JS project, but it showing any mongoose error

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I cloned an old project from git, it was working well. But now it is showing this error

```
(node:88186) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string. at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/Users/mobeenikhtiar/Downloads/slack's_downloaded_data/shopala-backend-56fb4bdcc8bd8024578ea82a0aef49c21a270563/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:684:11)
```

Comment: Thank you, I missed importing the env file.

require('dotenv').config();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue related to this, please follow this link for the answer.
[The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55267494/the-uri-parameter-to-openuri-must-be-a-string-got-undefined)

Comment: Use the `close` button when the question is a duplicate

Comment: I can't close this, because i don't have gold badge, can you please do this.

Comment: Thanks, this helped. I forgot to config dotenv in index.js